# How to not include '\n' and the next index entry while appending values from a certain index to a list

Tags: python, list

I have a data set that is in the format

```
100    domain    bacteria    phylum    chloroflexi    genus    caldilinea


200    domain    bacteria    phylum    acuuhgsdiuh    genus    blahblahbl


300
```

basically what i have been trying to do is create a function that scans through the different indexes separated by tabs and when it finds the desired entry, it appends the entry after to a list [e.g. search for 'domain' append 'bacteria'] . what i have works, except for the last entry where I would search for 'genus' it would append 'caldilinea\n\n200' which makes sense because it has line breaks after it but i don't know how to make it so it only appends the last index ['caldilinea' in this case] instead of the last index + line breaks + the first index on the row beneath it .

here is my code as of now:

```
in_file = open(input_file,'r')
lines = in_file.read()
segment_tab = lines.split('\t')

next_index = [segment_tab[position + 1] for position, entry in enumerate(segment_tab) if entry == 'genus']
```

when I print next_index it should give me

> 'caldilinea','blahblahbl'

but instead it is giving me

> 'caldilinea\n\n200','blahblahbl\n\n300'

my data is a lot more complex than this and has hundreds of rows

**How can i get it to not include the line breaks and the beginning index of the next row?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either split by lines and then split by tabs, or simultaneously split by both.

The former could be done like this:

```
lines = in_file.readlines()
segment_tab = [line.split('\t') for line in lines]
```

More idiomatic would be something like:

```
segment_tab = [line.split('\t') for line in in_file]
```

Note that this will give you a list of lists of strings, not just a list of strings. This is different than what you seem to expect, but is the more conventional approach.

The other approach is to split by both, like this:

```
lines = in_file.read()
segment_tab = re.split(r'\t|\n+', lines)
```

This is kind of unconventional (it treats groups of newlines just like a tab), but seems to be what you're asking for.

Note that you'll need to `import re` for this to work.

Comment: it works perfectly thank you . i'm confused on what r'\t|\n+' does exactly ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry That's a regular express that contains one-or-more of either a tab or a new-line character.

Comment: That requires a two-part answer: First, at the language level, the r prefix makes it a "raw" string, which pretty much just means that a backslash is just a backslash. By convention most people use them all of the time for regexes, as they tend to contain many backslashes. It would be equivalent to write `'\\t|\\n+'`, but that's a lot less readable.

Comment: @draconisthe0ry the other half is what chrisaycock said: a regular expression that matches either a single tab, or a group of one or more newlines. You can read the re module documentation or one of the many regular expression tutorials (or even books) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in open('input_file', 'r'):
    segment_tab = line.strip().split('\t')
```

This will give you `segment_tab = ['100', 'domain', 'bacteria', 'phylum', 'chloroflexi', 'genus', 'caldilinea']` for each line. Is this good enough?